# Transform Pauli basis to other basis

Tags: quantum-gate, pauli-gates

The Pauli basis is
\begin{align}
I=\left[\begin{matrix}
   1&0 \\
   0&1
\end{matrix}
\right],
\end{align}
\begin{align}
X=\left[\begin{matrix}
   0&1 \\
   1&0
\end{matrix}
\right],
\end{align}
\begin{align}
Y=\left[\begin{matrix}
   0&-i \\
   i&0
\end{matrix}
\right],
\end{align}
\begin{align}
Z=\left[\begin{matrix}
   1&0 \\
   0&-1
\end{matrix}
\right].
\end{align}
$I,X,Y,Z$ form a vector space. How to transform this pauli basis to another basis? How to perform this transformation? An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this consist in exploiting that the three Pauli matrices can be related to Cartesian axes of the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) (SU(2) is the double cover of SO(3)).

That means that you can perform rotations of those axes and obtain a new basis. Define the Pauli operator $\vec{\sigma}=(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)=(X,Y,Z)$. You can construct any other operator in a different axis by selecting a unit vector in the Bloch sphere $\hat{n}=(\cos\varphi\sin\theta,\sin\varphi\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ using polar coordinates ($\varphi$ azimuthal angle, $\theta$ polar angle).

Thus you can now replace $Z$ with a rotated operator $Z'=\vec{\sigma}\cdot \hat n$. The rest follows from the usual [coordinate transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) between polar and Cartesian, you can get two other ortogonal operators as
$$X'=X\cos\varphi\cos\theta+Y\sin\varphi \cos \theta-Z\sin\theta,$$
$$Y'=-X\sin\varphi+Y\cos\varphi.$$

For more general parametrisations you can use [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and Euler's angles.

Answer (score 0):

There is perhaps a better answer than this one.

Still, one approach is to note that $\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}\cong \mathbb{C}^2\otimes \mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{C}^4$ and recall the vectorization isomorphism $vec:\mathbb{C}^2\otimes \mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^4$; maps $vec(A)=\sum_i |v_i\rangle \otimes A|u_i\rangle$, for $|v_i\rangle$ and $|u_i\rangle$ orthonormal basis (o.n.b) for $\mathbb{C}^2$, note that each choice of o.n.b gives you an o.n.b for $\mathbb{C}^4$.For simplicity, consider the case where $|u_i\rangle=|v_i\rangle=|i\rangle$ for $i=1,2$.

Then the Pauli matrix basis is a basis for $\mathbb{C^4}$ under this isomorphism $vec(I)=(1,0,0,1)^T$, $vec(X)=(0,1,1,0)^T$, $vec(Y)=(0,i,-i,0)^T$, and $vec(Z)=(1,0,0,-1)^T$. From this, it is easy to construct a unitary that maps to or from this basis of vectors. For instance, if $e_1=(1,0,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0,0)^T$, etc... the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the Pauli basis is simply the unitary $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & i & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -i & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\\end{pmatrix}.$$ Reversing the $vec$ construction would give you back the Pauli matrices. Note that this could be done for any basis for $\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$.

That being said, if all you want to do is express a $2\times 2$ complex matrix $A$, that is given to you in the basis $\{B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4\}$, in the basis $\{C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4\}$ then this can be done by recalling that any $A$ can be decomposed in that basis, the same way you would in any vector space, that is $$A=
\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{Tr(A^*C_i)}{\|C_i\|_F^2}C_i,$$ where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.